# How do I change the universe of a Steam ID?

Tags: php, steam

I am trying to get the correct steam ID of a user from Discord using oauth2, but it returns the ID with the universe set to 0, rather than 1; which is the correct universe for public accounts, meaning that my program is unable to work as a result of this.

Here is the code which I have at the moment to fetch the user ID from the `$connections` variable.

```
$connections = $user->connections;
$item = null;
foreach($connections as $connection) {
if ($connection->type == "steam")  {
    $item = $connection;
    break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do this in order to get the correct steam ID

```
$badsteamid = decbin(intval($item->id));

$steamid = bindec(substr_replace($badsteamid,"1",strlen($badsteamid)-33,1));
```